# How to pass several POST parameters to mongodb and get matched result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB Collection **books** with 100 documents/rows. I use POSTMAN to make a POST request with 2 parameters "genre: sci fi" and "language: english". I want to get a simple json-response from my collection `books` with documents included this values only (in SQL I would make something like that: SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre="sci fi" AND language="english" , but I need this with nodejs/express/mongodb.)

Nodejs, Express and MongoDB is running properly and I created a collection with documents already:

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
Book = require('./models/books');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/booksdb');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB is running');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Also I can access my passed parameters with console.log:

```
app.post('/api/searchbooks', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.genre);
    console.log(req.body.language);

Book.getBooks(function(err, post){
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
   res.json(post);
});
```

But I don't get how to pass them to mongodb and get a proper response (documents that matched my search) and not my entire collection with 100 rows. I watched a dozen tutorials to mongodb and express but I can't figure it out. A working example would be realy great.

**books.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var booksSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    genre:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    language:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }},
    { collection: 'books'}
    );

    var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('books', booksSchema);

    module.exports.getBooks = function(callback, limit){
       Book.find(callback).limit(limit);
    }
```

**one document:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("97542a337653a7d6bf9cca88"), "genre" : "sci fi", "language" : "english", "year": "1999", "title" : "Foo" }
```

Comment: Have you created a mongoose data model/schema?

Comment: the query will depend on your mongo data model. So untill you share it nobody can answer it.

Comment: I posted more code, but this is not working and you can change it completely.

Comment: You are missing the query

Comment: Do you mean a collection document? I added one. If not, I don't know what you mean, sorry :(

Comment: I don't have more code, that is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this change in the  app.js

```
 Book.getBooks({genre : req.body.genre, language:req.body.language  }, 10, function(err, post){
   if (err){
    throw err;
  }
 res.json(post);
});
```

in books.js

```
module.exports.getBooks = function(query,limit, callback){
   Book.find(query).limit(limit).exec(callback);
}
```